# how to get distinct records from all columns from table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with 100 columns and i need to get distinct records from all the  columns from the table.
I used below query to get distinct records from table

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3,........ from test_table
```

but is there any good query to fetch distinct records from all the columns 
from table without mentioning column names in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want DISTINCT on all columns, and you want to select all columns, it couldn't be simpler:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a simpler way, 
You can use information_schema to get your columns and then use it.

```
    SELECT string_agg(column_name::character varying, ',') as columns
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
AND table_name   = 'table_name'
```

This will return you the list of columns in your table.

```
 SELECT string_agg(column_name::character varying, ',') as columns
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
    AND table_name   = 'table_name' \gset
```

You can refer to gset [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html),

For example, if your table has two columns 'a' and 'b', gset will store, 'a,b'.

`echo` might be used to check what gset has stored,

```
\echo :columns
```

The following query might help you,

```
select distinct :columns from table_name;
```